# python create a unexpected blank row below header

Tags: python

My code below create csv file and then adding random data to it.

Somehow, the first part of the code create a blank row below header.

Can anyone please help to fix the code to remove this blank row?

Thank you,

Hary

```
header_list = ["Firm", "hour", "unit sold", "product code", "dollar value"]
for i in range(3):
    # create file with header -----------
    with open(f'D:\\2000 transactions\\location_id_' + str(i) + '.csv', 'w',  newline='') as file:
        dw = csv.DictWriter(file, delimiter=',',fieldnames=header_list)
        dw.writeheader() # this line create a blank row below header


    # adding data to file ---------------
    for j in range(5):
        n = random.randint(1, 99)
        text = str(str(sp100_list['Name'].loc[n]) + ',' + str(random.randint(5, 20)) + ',' + str(random.randint(200, 1000)) + ',' + str(
            random.randint(100, 150)) + ',' + str(int(random.random() * 1000000)))
        myfile = open(f'D:\\2000 transactions\\location_id_' + str(i) + '.csv', 'a')
        myfile.write('\n' + text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you add unexpected blank row in the line `myfile.write('\n' + text)`,not `dw.writeheader()`. You add a `\n` first, which add a blank row to your file. Move the `\n` to backwards should solve it.

code:

```
import csv
header_list = ["Firm", "hour", "unit sold", "product code", "dollar value"]
for i in range(1):
    with open(f'test{str(i)}.csv', 'w',  newline='') as file:
        dw = csv.DictWriter(file, delimiter=',',fieldnames=header_list)
        dw.writeheader() # this line create a blank row below header
    for j in range(5):
        with open(f'test{str(i)}.csv', 'a',  newline='') as myfile:
            text = "1,1"
            myfile.write(text+'\n')
```

result:

```
Firm,hour,unit sold,product code,dollar value
1,1
1,1
1,1
1,1
1,1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can only use csv writer instead of DictWriter.here is example
use csv write to write header and rows

```py
header_list = ["Firm", "hour", "unit sold", "product code", "dollar value"]
for i in range(3):

    #create writer here
    with open(f'tmp_' + str(i) + '.csv', 'w') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
        #write header
        writer.writerow(header_list) 

        # adding data to file ---------------
        for j in range(5):
            n = random.randint(1, 99)
            writer.writerow([sp100_list['Name'].loc[n],random.randint(5, 20),
                    random.randint(200, 1000),random.randint(100, 150),
                    int(random.random() * 1000000)])
```